# Form post to Wordpress page = wrong template

Tags: templates, forms

I'm using permalinks and I have a page with a slug like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/jobs/
```

The page uses a specific template for itself.

On another page I have a form that I submit as POST to `http://www.mysite.com/jobs/`. However, when the form is submitted, it takes me to the proper `/jobs/` page, but the template is not correct. Even though the url is correct. I appears to use maybe the index or default template for some reason. If I click in the address bar of the browser and press enter to re-visit the same page, then the proper template appears.

It's like submitting a POST form to this page makes it use the wrong template even though the permalink slug is exactly the same as when I visit it normally.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your form elements aren't using any names that WordPress uses, like `name` or `s`, this will cause the behavior you describe because it changes the type of query. Give them all names you are certain are unique.

Comment: One of my form inputs was named "s". That was the problem. I guess Wordpress was trying to treat it as a normal site search. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I had a input named name... now I'm super-happy I found your answer!

Comment: My form input has the same as a custom post type and caused this problem. 

This note might help someone.